# EC2 Instance Network Error : "Request time out"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connectivity

We have EC2 Redhat instance with 1TB of volume. After modifying volume to 2TB, when we try to access server via SSH it throwing error as `Network Error : Request time out`.

We followed [Requesting Modifications to Your EBS Volumes - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requesting-ebs-volume-modifications.html) to modify the volume.

Could any one help me to fix this issue?

Debug Log:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\Max-Asset-03/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "<ip>" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <ip> [<ip>] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000001B6073FB750
debug1: connect to address <ip> port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host <ip> port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Use `ssh -vvv` to obtain more debug output, then add it to your Question. Double-check the IP address you are using, it might have changed if the instance was stopped/started. Check the Security Group configuration -- a timeout means that your computer was unable to reach the remote computer, so the problem is likely related to networking/reachability rather than the instance itself.

Comment: I updated question with debug log. Could you please check it ?

Comment: Did you confirm that the IP address is still associated with the EC2 instance? Are you able to SSH into any other EC2 instances that are in the same subnet? Sometimes, corporate networks blog SSH access. Are you connecting from a location that previously worked, or can you try it from another network (eg home, office, tethered via phone)? What is the configuration of the Security Group(s) associated with the instance?

Comment: If you turned off the machine (which I asume you did) and you didnt have an Elastic IP address, the IP that you used in the past wont work anymore, because the IPs change when an instance is turned on/offf (not rebooted)

Comment: this is most likely networking level issue. incorrect ip, security group issue. Also check your instance status check. There might be some issue with OS after you modified the volume.

Comment: IP address and Security are not changed. I am able to access other instance on same subnet and Security Group

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach i would take:

```
 1. Try doing a Telnet to port 22 from your env and see if it connects
 2. If it does not connect then you should look at your security group first and see if you have open inbound rule to port 22
 3. If you think you have the sec group open then i would look at NACL layer.
 4. If you think that is also not the issue, you should see are you in the public subnet
```

This should give u a good idea of what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Basically, "Network Error : Request time out" error occurs when there is a network related issue.

Possibilities that you can troubleshoot are as follows:

1. Make sure that your NACL rules are not being an obstacle.
2. There may be the chances of your IP address getting blacklisted.

[Visit [spamhaus.org](https://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/) for checking if your IP address has been black listed]. If yes, the whitelist the IP and try to login again.

3. Also, there might be a possibility that EBS volume have been corrupted due to the activities on your EC2 instance when it is in 'running' state. If yes, try to recover your EBS volume using the snapshot (incase you have taken it).

Hope this helps.